# Unity Скрыть UI картинку

Tags: unity3d

Для отключения GameObject в Unity есть .SetActive(), вопрос - как отключить иные объекты по типу картинок/кнопок?

Comment: "Картинки/Кнопки" - это компоненты, которые обязательно расположены в/на GameObject. Если нужно отключить *компонент* - используйте свойство "enabled" (enabled = false). Если нужно отключить сам объект с компонентом - то это Вы уже итак умеете.

Comment: хм, получилось. я немного неправильно это понял. спасибо

Comment: тогда перенесу в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Картинки", "Кнопки" и пр. - это "компоненты" с точки зрения логики Unity, которые **обязательно** расположены в/на GameObject.
Если нужно отключить **компонент** - используйте свойство "enabled"

`enabled = false;`

Если нужно отключить сам **объект** с компонентом - то это Вы уже итак умеете.

`gameObject.SetActive(false);`